# accessing windows server share on ubuntu 12.04 via fstab

Tags: samba, fstab

I want to give a ubuntu 12.04 user access to the shared folder of windows servers. I made the these changes to the `/etc/fstab`

```
//192.168.1.100/share  /home/user/share  cifs username=dem,password=****,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

The problem is that the user can't make any changes to it, despite this user has full access to this share directory on windows server.

please advice

Comment: Do you see the share?

Comment: yes, i can access the share but with read only.

Comment: please try by adding uid & gid options (e.g. uid=1000,gid=1000)

Comment: where do they stand in this commmand?

Comment: add it after `password=****,`

Comment: Did you give this user read and write permissions on the Windows server?

Comment: @ludicerZA As I can see, he has already mentioned that he gave full access to the user for the specific share.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add uid & gid that missing:

`//192.168.1.100/share /home/user/share cifs uid=1000,gid=1000,username=dem,password=****, iocharset=utf8, sec=ntlm 0 0`

from [mount.cifs manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/mount.cifs.8.html)---
uid=arg: sets the uid that will own all files on the mounted filesystem

To find the user's uid/gid that will have access to the share, run in terminal `id username`